# Tabbed Page Behavior causes app crash in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to implement an event to command behavior(as demonstrated by Xamarin:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Behaviors/EventToCommandBehavior)

As soon as I try to add a TabbedPage.Behaviors section to my TabbedPage.Xaml the app will crash on launch in iOS with the following exception:

```
    Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
Native stack trace:
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b48434b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000115be221e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b488442 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010c065e4d -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 195
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010ecb0619 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3827
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010ecacf69 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    6   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011890b723 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    7   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011890b59c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 189
    8   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011890b925 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b429311 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b40e59c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b40da86 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b40d494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010ecab7e6 -[UIApplication _run] + 434
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010ecb1964 UIApplicationMain + 159
    15  ???                                 0x000000012e4eb58c 0x0 + 5071877516
    16  ???                                 0x000000012e4eb1fd 0x0 + 5071876605

  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/44931ae8/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
  at TabDemo.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/Shared/git/Experiments/TabDemo/TabDemo.iOS/Main.cs:17
```

On Android the app simply hangs on launch and never displays the tabbed page.

MyTabbedPage.Xaml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabDemo.Views"
    xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:TabDemo.Views.Behaviors"
    x:Class="TabDemo.Views.MyTabbedPage">
    <TabbedPage.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior
            EventName="CurrentPageChanged"
            Command="{Binding OnCurrentPageChangedCommand}" />
    </TabbedPage.Behaviors>
    <NavigationPage
        Title="Main">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:MainPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage
        Title="Second">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:SecondPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Wiring up the behavior in the code behind leads to the exact same problem.  If I remove the behavior entry in the TabbedPage.Behaviors section the app runs fine on both platforms.

Can anyone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I've posted a sample app demonstrating the problem [up on github](https://github.com/jbachelor/TabbedAppSample/tree/master). I'll add branches to try out different answers. Thanks for your assistance, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you might need to change the type that EventToCommandBehavior inherits from. Open the EventToCommandBehavior.cs file and change:

```
public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<View>
```

to:

```
public class EventToCommandBehavior : BehaviorBase<VisualElement>
```

You will also need to modify the signature of two methods:

```
protected override void OnAttachedTo (View bindable)

protected override void OnDetachingFrom (View bindable)
```

to:

```
protected override void OnAttachedTo(VisualElement bindable)

protected override void OnDetachingFrom(VisualElement bindable)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @jgoldberger! It looks like you got me past the biggest initial hurdle. With the changes you suggested, the app runs again rather than crashing on launch, however, for some reason my DelegateCommand is not getting called. I'll continue to investigate. Thank you again! I've put the code up on GitHub if you're curious, with a branch called 'jganswer' in which I implemented your suggestions: [link](https://github.com/jbachelor/TabbedAppSample/tree/jganswer)

Comment: Ok... I found the reason the command was not executing. I had the namespace messed up in the ViewModel <face palm/>!

Comment: Updated, now working code is on github on the [jganswer branch](https://github.com/jbachelor/TabbedAppSample/tree/jganswer)... I just need to figure out how to get the newly selected tab name out of the event, and I'll be off and running! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

If you're following the straight up example for the EventToCommandBehavior, my guess would be that there is an exception being thrown because your command expects a different type than what is being passed in. Without seeing your project, or knowing what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to give you a clearer direction.

You might try taking a look at this Gist that provides an example of how to add a behavior to a TabbedPage on CurrentPageChanged: https://gist.github.com/dansiegel/cdc81671f3610d8992d70c65c202f0a4

Comment: Thanks very much, @dan-s! That Gist looks like just about exactly the sort of thing I'm looking for. Is this a future part of the Prism framework for Xamarin.Forms? I'm not exactly sure how to implement it, but I'll play around with it to see if I can get something like this working. If you happen to know of any code samples out there where someone actually uses the MultiPageNavigationBehavior in an app, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: @jbachelor You can always take a look at the [milestones](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/milestones) for Prism. One of the milestones for the 6.3 release for XF is to include this type of behavior which would be automatically attached by the NavigationService. I should add that you can currently utilize IActiveAware within TabbedPages in the 6.3 beta if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks, @dan-s! I'll go check out 6.3 pre-release and IActiveAware.

Comment: I tried to use IActiveAware without luck, where can I can find a useful sample?